# ActiveMQ Store but not forward

Tags: rest, jms, activemq-classic

I am setting up ActiveMQ, What I am trying to do is as follows..

Sender(SAP) to send a message to ActiveMQ to store the message on a queue.

A client can then on demand call the REST API to consume this message from the queue.

Currently what happens is for the first two attempts after the queue creation I am able to consume the message with the REST API,but on the third attempt when I post a new message the message is automatically dequeued,and when I try to consume nothing is returned ?

Is this scenario supposed to work ?

basically I do not want MQ to push the message to any consumer, rather wait for a consumer to consume on demand ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code for the consumer?

Comment: maybe you did not close the message consumer after processing the message? The message remains in queue if there is no active consumer.